# Entity Framework - View Sql using toTraceString

Tags: entity-framework, logging, entity-framework-5, generated-sql

I'm trying to view the generated sql that Entity Framework 5.0 generates from an entities query. All over the web, everyone says to cast the **IQuerable** object to an **ObjectQuery** object and then use the toTraceString() method to return the generated query.

However I keep getting an invalid case exception:

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'.
```

What is the new way to do this in Entity Framework 5?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can view the generated SQL from an IQueryable using `.ToString()`, e.g.

```
var query = context.People.Where(x => x.DomainId == 1);
Console.WriteLine(query.ToString());
```

Comment: Wow! That was easy. Thanks. I figured toString() with return the object type like it normally does.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using SQL Server? If so, try using the profiler. Tools->SQL Server Profiler in the development version of Management Studio

Comment: Oops - but that isnt using TraceString like you asked.